# Editing special text in labels

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I'm currently creating an app that shows how many likes/dislikes the user has on his videos. I would like my like/dislike text have 0.5 alpha. This is how my code looks like

My code looks something like this, so my question is how do I make the "likes/dislikes" text have 0.5 alpha ?

```
self.ratingLabel.text = @"%i likes %i dislikes", likes, dislikes;
```

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d likes %d dislikes", likes, dislikes];` perhaps? That thing won't compile.

Comment: You need to create an `NSAttributedString` with the proper formatting and set the label's `attributedText` property.

Comment: Could you show me a sample of NSAttributedString ?

Comment: Start with the reference docs then do a little google searching if needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a color with 0.5 as alpha component, form an existing color:

```
UIColor* color= [someColor colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.5];
```

Or from scratch:

```
UIColor* color= [UIColor colorWithRed: red green: green blue: blue alpha: 0.5];
```

Then you have to create an attributed string and set it as *attributedText* of your label. The attribute for the foreground color is *NSForegroundColorAttributeName*:

```
NSString* text= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i likes %i dislikes", likes, dislikes];
self.ratingLabel.attributedText= [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString: text attributes: @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color}];
```

Comment: I tried this and I replaced the "text" in the code to @"likes" and it only showed likes nothing else.

This is my current code

    self.ratingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ likes %@ dislikes", formatLikes, formatdisLikes];

Comment: @IamGretar This code is still incorrect because you aren't creating an attributed string. You need to create an attributed string with the *NSForegroundAttributeName*, like shown in my code.